# Power BI DAX related

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am having scenario to find out the solution,
Having one table with two columns
First Column is IP-Address
Second column is Date (Each month will single date )

As on today I am having past four months data & will add in coming months as well and I need classification based on given logic. Added image for required classification as additional column

1. I am struggling to get "Resurfaced" class - Which means When we compare Current month ID with older months

- If it is matching with previous month it will classified as "Carry forward"
- Else it should check older months data any where the id is matching that will be classified as "Resurfaced"
- If the Id is no where matching with older months data that will be "New"

| Date | IP address | Required Classification |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/23 | 1.1.300 | New |
| 01/01/23 | 1.2.400 | New |
| 01/02/23 | 1.1.100 | New |
| 01/02/23 | 1.2.500 | New |
| 01/02/23 | 1.2.600 | New |
| 01/03/23 | 1.1.1 | New |
| 01/03/23 | 1.2.300 | Resurfaced |
| 01/03/23 | 1.2.500 | Carry forward |
| 01/03/23 | 1.2.600 | Carry forward |
| 01/04/23 | 1.1.3 | New |
| 01/04/23 | 1.2.600 | Carry forward |

The 3rd column is required column classification.

Can anyone please look into this issue and do the needful.

I have used few conditions to get new through Dax.

```
New = 
VAR CurrentMonth = SELECTEDVALUE('YourTableName'[Month])

-- Check if CurrentMonth is blank
RETURN
IF(
    ISBLANK(CurrentMonth),
    BLANK(),
    VAR PreviousMonths =
        CALCULATETABLE (
            VALUES('YourTableName'[IP Address]),
            'YourTableName'[Date] < MINX(FILTER('YourTableName', 'YourTableName'[Month] = CurrentMonth), 'YourTableName'[Date])
        )
    RETURN
        CALCULATE (
            COUNTROWS(
                EXCEPT(
                    VALUES('YourTableName'[IP Address]),
                    PreviousMonths
                )
            ),
            'YourTableName'[Month] = CurrentMonth
        )
)
```